# Sitecore, and undesidered danish version when programatically adding an item

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, content-management-system, sitecore

I'm programatically adding a version to a sitecore database. The item is under workflow. Everything is ok, but I get my Item with an English and a Danish version on the workflow. I would like to get rid of the danish version or avoid creating it in the first place.
This is my code snippet

```
var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itm = database.GetItem(Constants.Sitecore.CommonPages.JOB_LISTINGS);

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    TemplateItem itemTemplate = database.GetItem(Constants.Sitecore.Templates.JOB);


    Item scInnerItem = itm.Add(ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(string.Format("{0} {1}", jb.JobId, jb.PositionTitle.RemoveSpecialCharacters())), itemTemplate);
    Job scJob = new Job(scInnerItem);

    using (new EditContext(scInnerItem))
        scJob.GetJobFromUserJob(jb);

    return (IBaseSitecoreItem)scJob;
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, Danish is one of the default languages for which the home page has a version, except English is the only installed language (by default). Maybe it's due to this. Delete the other language versions and try.

Answer (score 0):

Danish is indeed installed by default, but it should not be bugging/annoying you while pragmatically adding items. 
Here are two things to check:

1)What is the default language of your site, check  node in web.config
2)Does the Job template have any standard values, and are they by any chance in Danish?

Comment: rephrasing the question, is there any way I can avoid by code to insert a danish version?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few things:
Use the LanguageSwitcher to temprarily change the context language in your code. So switch it to english.

When you retrieve the parent item in which you store the new item, you must have already switched the language. 
Somehow the context language at the time of loading the parent item will define the language of the newly created version.

Hope that helps!